# How to make a model field as hyperlink in django models

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    trip_number = models.CharField(
        _("Trip Number"), max_length=128, db_index=True, unique=True, 
    blank=True)
```

what i am looking is to make this trip_number as hyperlink.

Comment: Hyperlink to where ?

Comment: I have make these field as a hyperlink and have to use in another model and have to display at detail level in admin(not in list_display)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you can use [URLField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#urlfield) to store hyperlinks, since this field type use URLValidator. URLField is a subclass of CharField, so you can use max_length.

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    trip_number = models.URLField(
        _("Trip Number"), 
        max_length=128, 
        db_index=True, 
        unique=True, 
        blank=True
    )
```

Comment: The biggest issue with that is it doesn't allow for links w/o a scheme (http(s)). I.e., a simple domain like `google.com` won't do.

Answer (score 1):

in the django admin you can use a function to display the value as a link. Here an example:

```
@admin.register(models.Trip)
class TripAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'trip_number', 'trip_link')

    def trip_link(self, obj):
        if obj.trip_number:
            return "<a href='%s'>Link</a>" % obj.trip_number
        else:
            return ''
```